# Perfect-forwarding while implementing emplace

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a class similar to `std::set`, and I was wondering if I handled the perfect forwarding right in implementing the `emplace` member function below. Basically, I forwarded calls to my class to a member `set`. But I wasn't sure whether I used `std::forward` enough.

Also, is there an easy way to tell when something is not forwarded as desired, and values are copied instead?

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class myset {
  std::set<T> m_s;
  typedef typename std::set<T>::iterator iterator;
  int cnt;
public:
  template <class... Args>
  pair <iterator,bool> emplace ( Args&&... args ) {
    pair<iterator,bool> p = m_s.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (p.second) //true if a new element was inserted
      cnt ++; //house keeping
    return p;
  }
};

int main() {myset<int> s;}
```

Comment: `Also, is there an easy way to tell when something is not forwarded as desired, and values are copied instead?` sure, try passing a struct with deleted copy-constructor, defaulted move-constructor, defaulted move-operator=. If something doesn't work, you gonna get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `std::forward` correctly. However, there are several other things worth noting about your code:

- why do you need a private counter instead of re-using `m_s.size()` that will automatically update itself after each `emplace_back()`?
- are you sure that you don't need additional template arguments `Compare` and `Allocator` instead of relying on their defaults `std::less<T>` and `std::allocator<T>`?
- since you are using C++11 already, please use `auto` to get rid of the `pair<itererator, bool>` (and if you are using C++14, you can also use `auto` for the return type).
- try also to write `using iterator = typename std::set<T>::iterator;` because left-to-right is much easier to parse than right-to-left of the current `typedef`.

Comment: Why should they be using `auto` in place of the pair, given they is using specific fields from it. Using a pair makes clear to the reader what type `p` has, and hence what fields/functions are there. In this case `auto` only makes it easier to write, but not to read.